Logarithmic curve formed by ratios of consecutive partition numbers
A few days ago, I was playing around with integer partitions, and I came across this interesting curve:



As you may have guessed from the title, these are the graphs defined by $$f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{p(x-1)}$$where $p(x)$ is the number of integer partitions of x. When I first looked at these curves, a logarithmic decay curve came to mind. Even though this curve is not perfect, it is extremely smooth when you zoom out a little bit. Of course, if we could somehow find an exact algebraic expression that perfectly simulates this graph, we have essentially found a closed-form expression for $p(x)$, as $$p(x) = \frac{p(x)}{p(x-1)} * \frac{p(x-1)}{p(x-2)} * \dots * \frac{p(3)}{p(2)} * \frac{p(2)}{p(1)}$$ I have asked this question as I believe that a curve this smooth must have an algebraic expression that correctly (exactly) simulates the curve at higher values of x.
Note: The graphs that you see have been generated using Sage code. Here it is:
def ratio(n):
    r = Partitions(n).cardinality() / Partitions(n-1).cardinality()
    return float(r)

x_vals = range(1, 10^2)
y_vals = [ratio(n) for n in x_vals]

list_plot(list(zip(x_vals, y_vals)), plotjoined=True, axes_labels=['x', 'y'])

Of course, we can't afford even the smallest error in the values of y, as many small errors, when multiplied, will compound to give us a number that is quite far from the one that we want.
Edit: Some more graphs



Congratulations for the improvement of your text : it is well written and concise, maybe even too much concise...

Thank you for the sarcasm.

I find it a bit unclear what you want: Do you want a formula that is exactly equal to $f$, or do you want a very good approximation of $f$?
You write that you want a closed form expression that "simulates" $f$ exactly for high values of $x$ - but you say yourself, "... the curve is not perfect, [but] it is extremely smooth when you zoom out a little bit". Zooming out is precisely the same as approximating. The actual function is an erratic integral function, not even a priori defined for $x\notin\Bbb{N}$, so assuming it will be exactly equal to some nice closed expression is a bit much. Compare it to the prime counting function $\pi(x)$.
In fact, the partition function is so well studied that no one expects there to be a nice closed form - and as you also wrote, a closed form for $f$ will essentially imply a closed form for $p$.
However, this also means that many excellent bounds are available. You should be readily able to produce a bound for $f$ using bounds for $p$, e.g. here Upper and Lower Bound on Partition Function. These exactly capture that when you zoom out, your function appears smooth. More precisely, you should be able to find a nice closed-form approximation, call it $g(x)$, such that $|f(x)-g(x)|\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

When you put it that way, I understand how it might be unclear. Obviously, a formula that is exactly equal to $f$ can't be found, but I want a closed form expression that "simulates" f exactly for high values of $x$, which means that it may not be exact for small values, but it should be exact for higher values.

If we do that, $p(x)$ could be expressed as $\prod_{i=1}^{n} {a_i}$ where $a_i = \frac{p(i)}{p(i-1)}$. Then, $a_i$ could be a sequence, of which $a_i$ could be generated using a closed form expression for higher values of $i$.

@AkshajMishra Being equal for higher values of $x$ is just as good as being equal for all $x$, so you still run into all the problems I listed above. If you zoom in enough for high values of $x$, the function will still look like it did for small values of $x$, i.e. highly zig-zaggy and weird. The best you can hope for is approximation.

I added some more graphs if you want to look at them.

As I said, an approximation would lead to large errors when I calculate the actual value of $p(x)$ for large $x$

Wikipedia states that "No closed-form expression for the partition function is known", what you ask is too much since it is a well identified open question.
As @SomeCallMeTim says, the asymptotic smoothness can be shown by the known bounds, but apparent smoothness does not tell that it is easy to compute.
Instead, what you ask seems to be, more precisely than a closed form, just an efficient way to compute the exact partition function (without approximation). A nice recurrence gives a $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm to compute $p(n)$.

Are there no known techniques that simulate graphs, other than non-linear regression?

Just because its a well identified open question doesn't mean we should give up on it. I get what you're saying, but is it wrong to try?

@AkshajMishra what do you mean with non-linear regression? If you talk about interpolation , it is for a finite number of points, and regression is not supposed to pass exactly by the points,  only to be a good fit. This is not wrong to try, but don't be too delusional about it. The partition function is sufficiently famous that there are probably eminent mathematician that tried to do it.

Finding closed form for combinatorial problems is notably difficult, and is only possible for a handful of easy problems. In fact, we can prove that almost all the series don't have a closed form. It is probable there is no closed form for this (but proving such a claim is much more difficult than proving there is one, hence why it is open).

You are right. I shall give up on this.
